# Open Outlook.exe from cmd with body text containing newlines

Tags: windows, command-line, outlook, cmd, outlook-2010

I'm trying to open Microsoft Outlook 2010 from cmd, but I'd like the body of the email to contain line breaks/newlines.

```
"C:\Programs\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note /m "myemail@email.com&cc=seconda.address@email.com&subject=Test&body=Line 1 \r\n Line 2"
```

With that outlook 2010 opens correctly with email addresses, the subject but i can't figure out how to automatically insert a newline.

I've tried with /0, 
, 
, , \r\n, \r\r, $_ but it still write it as simple text.

I know that %20 character puts is a whitespace, but i need a newline.

Is that even possible? No .bat or stuff, just plain command line (windows XP)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
"C:\Programs\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note /m "myemail@email.com&cc=seconda.address@email.com&subject=Test&body=Line 1 %0D%0ALine 2"
```

Replace the `\r\n` with `%0D%0A` you can also remove the space on the next line by removing space after adding `%0D%0A` so something like this `%0D%0A`Line 2

Below is a link to read up and understand it better. It might come in handy for other possible questions you might have in future

[WIKIPEDIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: Guys, if someone writes a great answer, please up vote rather than saying "thanks".