# Creating email via CMD batch script, how to insert txt file contents to the body of email?

Tags: email, batch-file, cmd, outlook, io-redirection

I have this script to create an email from CMD script and insert `TO`, `SUBJECT` and `BODY` automatically.

I have a few variables already:

- `%USERNAME%`
- `%TICKETNO%`

It works, it creates a new email, puts the `TO` address, `SUBJECT` and `BODY` automatically. Variables work fine.

Now I want to insert the body as a sort of variable (redirected input to the command from varying text documents)

```
cd "c:\program files\microsoft office\office14\" 
start outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "%USERNAME%@domain.com&subject=Request %TICKETNO% Completed&body=exampletext”
```

Whatever I tried I can’t make it insert after `&body` input redirected from a text file. For now I'm just specifying the text document but I can't get the syntax right. I don't really know how to do it but I tried a bunch of things last night and just couldn't get it to work.

Example (pardon my noobishness):

```
start outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "%USERNAME%@domain.com&subject=Request %TICKETNO% Completed&body=” <body.txt
```

How can I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: Duplicate of [Open Outlook.exe from cmd with body text containing newlines](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20218018) ?

Comment: ALSO im very new to this so while there may be the proper/best practice way of doing this it would be good to know however I probably need the easiest way so I can understand how it works :)

Comment: With delayed expansion enabled (`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`), do `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("body.txt") do set "body=!body!%%~I%%0D%%0A"` to store the contents of body.txt into `%body%` with line breaks replaced with the hex representations of carriage return + line feed.  Then in your `outlook.exe` command, you can use `"...&body=!body!"`.  Be advised that batch commands are limited to 8191 characters, and `!body!` will probably need further URL encoding.  You might be better off using WSH + CDO, or use blat or postie or some other 3rd party utility.

Comment: ok ill try that later after work :D thanks for the reply

Comment: sorry i suck but i couldn't get it to work. how would you actually put that? minus the instructions

Comment: @rojo

any help would be appreciated. I got this... but it still doesn't add anything to the BODY of the email, subject and to fields are working great.

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16" 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
do for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in "c:\test\body.txt" do set body=!body!%%~I%%0D%%0A
start outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "%CALLUSERNO%@domain.com.au&subject=Request %TICKETNO% Completed&body=!body!"

Answer (score 0):

Create the text file as HTML file and attach the HTML file using below syntax

```
start outlook.exe /c ipm.note /a 'html' /m "%USERNAME%@domain.com&subject=Request %TICKETNO% Completed&body
```